# Extra column coming in database when using @OneToMany mapping

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, one-to-one, jpa

[image]I was creating a three table entities, Student, College and address. When I try to insert data into address table I am getting one extra column(student_STUDENT_ID) only in address table in database. Please find attached screenshot. I am not able able to make out why this fields is coming ? Can it be removed ? Below is the code for mapping these three  entities.

Address table -

```
@ManyToOne
private Student student;
//setters and getters
```

Student table -

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="COLLEGE_ID")
    private College college;
     //getters and setters 

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID")
    private Set<Address> addr;
    //getters and setters
```

College table -

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="college",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Student student;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving @JoinColumn to Address class

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID")
private Student student;
```

Then in your Student Table, add mappedBy to @OneToMany

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="student")
private Set<Address> addr;
```

Comment: The extra table was not there now, but the value in STUDENT_ID column is coming NULL.

Comment: Are you setting the student when you're creating an Address?

Comment: thanks for reminding, was just going through code and found the problem was going to  post the same.

Answer (score 0):

The real configuration should be like this -

Address class -

```
  @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID")
        private Student student;
//getters and setters
```

Student class-

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="student")
            private Set<Address> addr;
      //getters and setters
```

No changes in college class.